# rails 3 routing question (Routing Error "No route matches …")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3 and I think I'm having a moderately simple problem with routing.

I have a model called `AdvancedQuery`. 
Its controller is `AdvancedQueriesController`.  *Almost* everything is done in the standard rails way except for the routing.  I wanted to change the names of the URLs and I wanted to change a few other things (see below).

Here is the relevant portion of my routes.rb file

```
get   "advanced_query" => "advanced_queries#new", as: :new_advanced_query
post  "advanced_query(/:hash_value)(/:page)" => "advanced_queries#create",  as: :create_advanced_query
get   "advanced_query/:hash_value(/:page)"  => "advanced_queries#search",  as: :advanced_query_search
```

Here is the behavior that I **expect** when working with AdvancedQuery:

1. User goes to http://localhost:3000/advanced_query (get request) and the browser invokes the "new" method in `advanced_queries_controller`. `new.html.haml` is rendered which shows the user a standard form to fill out.
2. User then enters data into the search form and presses "Submit"
3. "Submit" invokes the "create" method and creates an "AdvancedQuery" record in the database.  The AdvancedQuery object has a 32-character hash associated with it that 1) identifies the query and 2) is used as part of the resulting URL (see step 4).
4. The create method redirects to the "search" method where the AdvancedQuery object is used to search a 2nd model (called BusinessModel).  The server then renders `search.html.haml` then shows the results of the AdvancedQuery and it re-renders the original form on the same page as the results in case the user wants to run a new search.  The URL generated here is: http://localhost:3000/advanced_query/blah (where blah is a 32-character hash that's specifically associated with the query).
5. Now the user enters a new search term using the form from the web-page generated in Step 3.  He presses "submit" and the "create" method should be invoked again (i.e. we re-do Steps 3 & 4). i.e. Create a new AdvancedQuery.

Here's what happens in reality:

Steps 1 - 4 work as expected.  Step 5 gives me a Routing Error **`"No route matches "/advanced_query"`**

Both the `new.html.haml` and the `search.html.haml` files render the same partial (called `_form.html.haml`).

So, if I look at `_form.html.haml`, I don't really see anything wrong:

```
= form_for(@advanced_query, url: create_advanced_query_path) do |f|
  .actions
   # other generic form-related stuff
```

Here is the relevant portion of my controller

```
  def new
    @advanced_query  = AdvancedQuery.new
  end

  def create
    advanced_query  = AdvancedQueryBuilder.build_advanced_query_from_post(request, params, current_user)
    redirect_to(advanced_query_search_path(hash_value: advanced_query.hash_value))
  end

  def search
    return render :bad_request unless request.get?
    @advanced_query  = AdvancedQuery.find_by_hash_value_and_user_id(params[:hash_value], current_user.id)
    @results              = BusinessModel.advanced_search(@advanced_query)
  end
```

Any thoughts on what's causing my routing error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your parentheses in routes.rb might not be matched correctly - do you mean to have

```
post  "advanced_query(/:hash_value(/:page))" => "advanced_queries#create",  as: :create_advanced_query
```

instead of

```
post  "advanced_query(/:hash_value)(/:page)" => "advanced_queries#create",  as: :create_advanced_query
```

?

Section 3 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html might be able to help; it's not entirely clear what you're looking to pass in.

Comment: You're right about the parens not being correct, but even when I "fix" the syntax problem that you point out, I still get the same routing error.  my new line in the routes.rb file is: post "advanced_query/(:hash_value(/:page))"

Comment: Whoops, sorry - see my edit above. The / should be inside the parentheses, not outside.

Comment: Thanks.  I understood what you were trying to say (my syntax for the optional "slugs" was incorrect), but it turns out that my form was doing a "PUT" when I thought it was doing a POST.  Not sure why that is, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes file should read:

```
get   "/advanced_query" => "advanced_queries#new", :as => :new_advanced_query
post  "/advanced_query(/:hash_value(/:page))" => "advanced_queries#create",  :as => :create_advanced_query
get   "/advanced_query/:hash_value(/:page)"  => "advanced_queries#search",  :as => :advanced_query_search
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out the error, although I'm not quite sure *why* the error is taking place.

Turns out that even though the form rendered on search.html.haml is listed as "POST", and even though the log-file says that it's a POST, it turns out that it's a PUT!

so, if I modify my routes.rb file like this:

```
get   "advanced_query" => "advanced_queries#new", as: :new_advanced_query
post  "advanced_query(/:hash_value(/:page))" => "advanced_queries#create",  as: :create_advanced_query
put   "advanced_query(/:hash_value(/:page))" => "advanced_queries#create", as: :create_advanced_query
get   "advanced_query/:hash_value(/:page)"  => "advanced_queries#search",  as: :advanced_query_search
```

Then there is no Routing Error.